# Can't get my button click to load a new web page - android studio

Tags: android, webview, radio-button, clicklistener

new to app development, i'm trying to load a webpage in the background when the user clicks on my button, it doesn't seem to be working can anyone help me out with what's wrong?

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.myPlayButton);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                WebView mWebView;
                mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.RadioWebView);
                mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                mWebView.loadUrl("http://teamrock.planetwideradio.com:8000/teamrockhigh");
            }});
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: Have you got `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` within you manifest file?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if webview is the right thing for live radio streams.
Consider using one of these:

- [Android's media player - the most simple](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)
- [Exoplayer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html)
- [AAC Player](https://github.com/vbartacek/aacplayer-android)